# How can I get the link in this button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-scraping

I found this `button` in a website that I want to get the `link` where it is pointing but I can't find the `href` tag, where can the `href` tag be?

```
<button aria-label=“..“><span>...</span></button>
```

EDIT:

- [This](https://resultados.gob.ar/elecciones/3/0/1/-1/-1) is the website.
- This is the button I want to get the link from:
  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no anchor element or onclick attribute visible on the button html code, possibly it has a JavaScript listener attacked that is triggering the redirect on click like:

```
 document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "www.yoursite.com";
};
```

If you have access to see the page JavaScript, you may want to scrape that info from there. If the page is very complex, it may be very hard to know where the trigger is being created just by scraping. But this is something you usually can't automate.

If the button is part of a form element, you may be able to see the form action and scrape it from there, still there is a chance that the form submit event is routed though JavaScript as well.

With the given page, what can I tell is that resulting pages have the following format:

```
https://resultados.gob.ar/elecciones/3/[NUMBER]/1/-1/-1/
```

If you replace number with a value between 1-24 you get to a page corresponding to the ordinal element of the link you gave.
You may want to scrape the data from each of the 24 possible values given that there is no expectation about the links changing overtime.

Setting the value to zero gives the initial page.
There is no need to write the name after the URL.
Furthermore, a 403 response is given but you still get html and content that looks like is loaded through JavaScript.

If you want the raw data, your best bet is using this:

```
https://resultados.gob.ar/assets/mapas/[number].json
```

But then still you would need to understand that data which is not trivial.